# How many characters can we store on a double word

Tags: string, assembly, data-representation

I didn't understand the difference between strings with `dword`, `word`, `qword`, etc. I always use `byte` which can hold 1 byte, but when we want to use a string and not just a char, the assembler do it like `{'a', 'b', 'c'}` to represent a string just like *C*.

So when should I use for example `dword` when working with strings in assembly?

Comment: Depending on assembler, that usually just ensures that the entire string takes up a whole number of dwords. This is useful for maintaining alignment for following things.

Comment: Usually never.  If you want later stuff aligned, using an `align` directive after the string is clearer.  Which assembler did you have in mind?  I guess you mean x86 because most other ISAs don't have qwords.

Comment: A word is 2 bytes, a dword (double word) is 4 bytes and a qword (quad word) is 8 bytes.

Comment: In C, a string is a sequence of chars. In asm a string is a sequence of bytes, words, dwords or qwords. In asm there is nothing special about chars - they are just like integers. If you are dealing with strings of ANSI chars, use `LODSB/MOVSB/STOSB`; if you are dealing with unicode strings, use `XXXSW`; for USC32 strings, use `XXXSD`.

Comment: Apparently you're using NASM syntax based on a link to a book in another question